# Custom line-spacing inside editor?

Tags: lyx

Is there a way to set a custom line spacing for the editor without changing the line spacing of the output document?

Just as I can, for example, set `\screen_font_roman "Verdana"` in the lyx preferences file to have the text display in a font suitable for screen-reading in the editor (without changing the output document).

Background: For texts with single line spacing (on the output side / as set in the Document properties), the text display of the LyX Editor looks a bit too crammed for my taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, to my understanding, not currently possible. There is an open feature request for adjusting line spacing separately in output and input:

- https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9838

(Though this was for the opposite case, wanting less line spacing in a double-spaced document, but the principle is the same.)

Answer (score 1):

You can "cheat" to obtain the desired behavior:

1. Choose the desired line spacing for LyX in LyX.
2. Add `\usepackage{setspace}` to your LyX preamble.
3. In the beginning of your document, add a Latex code (ERT) inset with `\setstretch{1}`.

Then the document will compile with your LyX chosen line spacing, but in the beginning of the document switch to line spacing 1, without LyX's view changing.